# Errai Bus (Newbie) - Without CDI - Quick Q

Tags: errai

Errai seems like a really neat project. We just started working with it to port some of the GWT stack to errai.

With the Bus (I guess the most famous part of Errai), I had an extremely quick Q. We still havent brought in CDI.. will do at some point after some ofthe core refactoring is done.

Here goes the Q:

For our sample app - I have a client side code (bus listenining snippet below):

public void onModuleLoad() {

```
 bus = ErraiBus.get();

 initEBus();


 /.... then create the login panel with login button etc./
```

}

```
       private void initEBus() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println("initbus");
            bus.subscribe("Login", new MessageCallback() {


                public void callback(CommandMessage message) {
                     /**
                      * When a message arrives, extract the "text" field and
                      * do something with it
                      */
                    System.out.println( message.get(String.class, "text"));
                    }

                @Override
                public void callback(Message message) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }           
            });
        }
```

On the Server Side (the call happens via RPC when a login button is pressed):

private MessageBus msgBus = ErraiBus.get();

```
@Override

public Boolean doLogin(String username, String password) {


// TODO Auto-generated method stub


System.out.println("dispatching message");


msgBus.send(MessageBuilder


        .createMessage()


        .toSubject("Login")


        .with("text", "Hi There").done().getMessage());


return true;

}
```

When I run this, the server seems to be sending a message (I can only assume as there are no errors and the method does return true successfully), but the client never gets the message and doesnt print anything.

I am assuming we are doing something extremely silly or missing something .... Can anyone tell me what we are doing wrong?

Thanks much,

Mike,

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things you might want to look at:

Firstly, you're mixing levels of abstraction in this example. Although it's totally fine to write an app that uses the low-level MessageBuilder and MessageCallback API in some places, Errai RPC in other places, and CDI events and observers in other places yet, I can't recommend mixing and matching these levels of abstraction within the same use case (for example, responding to an RPC call using the MessageBuilder).

So in the case, above, I'd recommend that you choose either to return a value from your Errai RPC method, and receive that value in a RemoteCallback on the client:

```java
@Inject Caller<MyRpcService> myRpcService;

public void doRpcCall() {
  myRpcService.call(new RemoteCallback<String>() {
    @Override public void callback(String response) {
      System.out.println("Got RPC response from server: " + response);
    }
  }).doLogin(username, password);
}
```

Or if you do prefer to work directly with the low-level bus API, do something like this on the server:

```java
@Service
public void doLogin(Message message) {

    // dig out message parts for username and password ...

    MessageBuilder.createConversation(message)
        .toSubject("Login")
        .with("text", "Hello, World!")
        .done().reply();
}
```

Secondly, in your example server-side code, the message you're sending would be a broadcast message to the Login topic. Note that the code above sends a private reply just to the one client who invoked your service method. From the context of your question, I think this is the behaviour you were intending.

*PS: this question was cross-posted to the [Errai Community forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/228829). I originally posted this answer there, and I am re-posting it here for the convenience of others.*